# Importing common files to Sage

Tags: python, sage

I'd like to import some utility files in a separate directory to my project, e.g. so that I can do `import util` from the Sage prompt.  Adding that directory to the `SAGE_PATH` variable allows me to do so,   however doing so will cause problem when I want to read the document of any function in SAGE.  For example,

```
sage: solve??
```

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

....

ImportError: No module named conf

Any idea how to properly import files from a different directory ?

Answer (score 1):

The [standard way to import a file](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/programming.html) is simply

```
sage: load /path/to/foo.py
```

or

```
sage: attach /path/to/foo.py
```

or `foo.sage`, as the case may be.  If you always want this to happen, there is a file called `init.sage` you can create in your `DOT_SAGE` directory (usually at `$HOME/.sage/`) you can use.

Comment: hi, instead of adding a single file -- I want to add a whole directory  consisting of *.py files.  How to do so ?  In normal python I can do so by setting the PYTHONPATH=/dir/   but doing so with SAGE_PATH does not work well (cause problem when reading document as given above).

Comment: In order words -- I want to make SAGE awares and looks at certain directories for modules when I do the command  import module